# FME: Count crossings of roads and waterways

Tags: intersection, fme-form, fme-transformer

I have two datasets from OSM for a small region: roads and waterways. I want to count the "bridges" resp. all kinds of crossings between roads and waterways in FME. I can't find the right Transformer to do this (or I just don't see the right options if I already found a suitable transformer). I tried e.g. "Intersector", "LineOnLineOverlayer", "SpatialFilter". Maybe I'm just missing a small detail. What Transformer and options should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I had to use these Transformers: Intersector > ListHistogrammer > ListElementCounter > Tester - as shown below. I used the exposed fme_basename attribute to create the list.

[image]

Test result in QGIS:

[image]

Here's the answer in the [FME forum](https://community.safe.com/s/question/0D54Q00009kSFg4SAG/how-can-i-count-crossings-of-roads-and-waterways).

Answer (score 1):

Create a list with the Intersector, then check the results with a ListHistogrammer and Tester - assuming there are 2 possible line types.

[image: workspace]

Comment: Thank you, Dan! Just for clarification: The "Intersector" takes a "mixed" input of both the waterways and the roads layer? I'm asking because in your screenshot there's only one input.

Comment: Yes, it's both sets of features getting intersected against each other and within each set. The ListHistogrammer and Tester separate the intersections (nodes) of just waterways or roads from intersections between waterways and roads.

Comment: I don't manage to get it work Here's what I did: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3xBw.png). I have 2 OSM input layers and not one, so I can't distinguish by type. I exposed the fme_basename for the list, but the Tester does not detect the correct nodes when I check if the histogram{0}.count equals 2. Do you have another hint for me?